# SQl query showing opposite values

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Working on a sql query to show T_Temperatur and T_Badende_per_Time and the values. My sql query changes the comma to dot for the values with Cast, that is not the problem. The problem is that my sql query chose the values of the oppositite title, as you can see here:

SQL:

```
SELECT routines.date, routines.time, 
SUM( IF( measurements.title =  'T_Temperatur', CAST( REPLACE( routines.value,  ',',  '.' ) AS DECIMAL( 18, 2 ) ), 0 ) ) AS T_Temperatur, 

SUM( IF( measurements.title =  'T_Badende_per_Time', CAST( REPLACE( routines.value,  ',',  '.' ) AS DECIMAL( 18, 2 ) ), 0 ) ) AS Badende,

SUM( IF( measurements.title =  'T_Luft_temperatur', CAST( REPLACE( routines.value,  ',',  '.' ) AS DECIMAL( 18, 2 ) ), 0 ) ) AS Luft_Temp

FROM routines
INNER JOIN measure_routine ON routines.id = measure_routine.routine_id
INNER JOIN measurements ON measure_routine.measure_id = measurements.id
GROUP BY routines.date, routines.time
ORDER BY routines.date, routines.time;
```

[image]

My database is build  up with

routines:

[image]

measure_routine:

[image]

measurements:

[image]

Comment: You have the parms the wrong way round within the SUMs. Ie, you check it the measurement title is T_Temperatur and if it is you use 0 as the value for summing up T_Temperatur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swap the parameters in the `IF()` function, you return `0` if the condition is true!

IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)

If expr1 is TRUE (expr1 <> 0 and expr1 <> NULL) then IF() returns expr2; otherwise it returns expr3.

```
SELECT routines.date, routines.time, 
   SUM(IF(measurements.title='T_Temperatur', CAST(REPLACE(routines.value,',','.' ) AS DECIMAL(18,2)), 0)) AS T_Temperatur, 
   SUM(IF(measurements.title='T_Badende_per_Time', CAST(REPLACE(routines.value,',','.') AS DECIMAL(18,2)), 0)) AS Badende
FROM routines
INNER JOIN measure_routine ON routines.id = measure_routine.routine_id
INNER JOIN measurements ON measure_routine.measure_id = measurements.id
order by routines.date, routines.time
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried it but unsure what you ment. Could you please show how ? I have inserted the sql query in the edit. Danke schön!

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But when I tried to add another measurements title as shown in edit. I get alot of null values. The insert of the Badende_per time and Temperatur is on the same time, but not luft_temperatur.